# Convert string to decimal fail

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010

because I can not convert correctly? what am I doing wrong? I Need My variable value is identical to the string type .

I have to use another type ?

```
static void Stringparadecimal()
{
     string vcarga = "1324.54";
     decimal vcargadec = decimal.Parse(vcarga);

     Console.WriteLine("Convertendo String vcargad para formato decimal ");
     Console.WriteLine("Tipo da variavel vcargadec : " + vcargadec.GetType());
}
```

Comment: What is your `CurrentCulture`?

Comment: Have you seen http://pt.stackoverflow.com/?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Specify the format info by supplying the correct culture (in this case, `InvariantCulture` means US English):

```
decimal.Parse("1324.54", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I wonder why when I use .Parse not translate the same way?

Comment: Because your default culture settings are different, probably because your PC has another language installed.

Answer (score 0):

You have to take into account the culture in which you are parsing the decimal value. Some cultures consider `'.'` to be the decimal point, some other cultures consider `','` instead. It is always a good practice to specify the culture to use when doing decimal values parsing. In your case, supply `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` to the `Double.Parse` method.

Comment: Thank you for your attention I can not yet announce you as useful answer, do not have enough points = /

Answer (score 0):

try this one...

```
decimal d = decimal.Parse("1324.54", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
Console.WriteLine(d.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Convert.ToDecimal("1324.54", System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US"), "{0:c}".
```

You may have to change from en-US to whichever country that you're writing to code for.

Comment: That is the other way around...